# C++ N-ary tree, building a custom iterator with postfix operator taking in a parameter

Tags: c++, tree, iterator

I am trying to build a N-ary tree custom iterator. The nodes in the tree (`MoveTreeNode*`) have member values `MoveTreeNode* m_parent` to go to the previous node, and `vector <MoveTreeNode*> m_children` to go to the next nodes.

I want my iterator's postfix operator to take the parameter value `int i` which represents the index where the iterated node should descend in its `m_children` vector.

The key of the node is an object of type `Move`.

### MoveTreeNode.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Move.hpp"

using namespace std;

class MoveTreeNode {
    public: 
    MoveTreeNode(Move&);

    Move& m_move; // Key
    MoveTreeNode* m_parent; // To go to previous move      
    vector<MoveTreeNode*> m_children;   // To to go to next move
};
```

### MoveTree.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Move.hpp"
#include "MoveTreeNode.hpp"

using namespace std;

class MoveTree {
    public: 
    MoveTreeNode* m_root = nullptr; // Root of the tree

    // ( ... some member functions here)

    struct Iterator {
        using iterator_category = bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type   = ptrdiff_t;

        Iterator(MoveTreeNode* ptr): m_node(ptr) {};

        MoveTreeNode& operator*() const { return *m_node; }
        MoveTreeNode* operator->() { return m_node; }

        // Prefix increment
        // Iterator& operator++(int i) { 
        //      m_node= m_node->m_children.at(i); return *this; 
        // }  
        // ^^^^^^error : cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone

        // Postfix increment
        Iterator operator++(int i) { 
              Iterator tmp = m_node; m_node= m_node->m_children.at(i); return tmp; 
        }

        // Prefix decrement
        Iterator& operator--() { m_node = m_node->m_parent; return *this; }  

        // Postfix decrement
        Iterator operator--(int) { 
              Iterator tmp = m_node; m_node = m_node->m_parent; return tmp; 
        }

        friend bool operator== (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { return a.m_node== b.m_node; };
        friend bool operator!= (const Iterator& a, const Iterator& b) { return a.m_node!= b.m_node; };

        private:
        MoveTreeNode* m_node;
    };
    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(m_root); }
    Iterator end()   { return Iterator(nullptr); } 
};
```

#### Issues encountered

- Is it possible to have the increment operator overloaded such that it takes in a parameter, in this case an integer representing an index ?
- I am not sure whether both prefix and postfix operators have to be specified? If I never use the prefix operator can I just define the postfix operator ? Because in the above snippet of code if I uncomment the prefix definition then I get the compilation error *cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone* and I am not sure how to respond to that.
- It's my first time trying to build a custom iterator, is my above struct correct, or is there something I am missing and should modify ?

Comment: There's no way to pass a parameter to an increment operator, whether prefix or postfix (what do you imagine the calling syntax to look like?). The `int` parameter of a postfix operator is a dummy, it only exists to allow you to write two operators with the same name. Probably the easiest and cleanest solution would be to give the iterator a named function, like `moveToChild(int child_index)`. That said, I'm not sure I understand how callers are supposed to use such an iterator.

Comment: The pre/post operators are most often defined by using one in the other.